# Read a text file line by line using Win32 API

Tags: c, windows, file, winapi

I have a created a text file in my program in which I have saved IP addresses and port numbers of the clients that connect to my server. After every 30 secs, I want to read the IP and port number of a client from the text file, send some data to that client, wait for the reply, read the IP and port number of the second client and so on for the other clients.

What I have done:

```
fgets ( line, sizeof line, fp ); /* read a line */
{
    MessageBox(NULL,
               line,
               "First Line of File",
               MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
fp=fp++; //move to the next line
fgets ( line, sizeof line, fp ); /* read a line */
{
    MessageBox(NULL,
               line,
               "Second Line of File",
               MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
```

When the above code is executed, the first line and second line read from the text file are the same.

My text file looks like this:

```
10.0.1.25
56732

10.0.1.25
56733

10.0.1.25
56733

10.0.1.25
56733
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to remove this line from your code

```
fp=fp++; //move to the next line
```

the `fgets()` function move the position of reading file automatically to the next line

to read and to split data (IP + port) of your file,  I suggest to you to use `fscanf()` instead of `fgets()`

**example:**

```
char ip[16];
int port;

while (fscanf(fp, " %s %d", ip, &port) > 0) {
    printf("ip: %s, port: %d", ip, port);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion: `strtok` to cut each line. first part is ip, second part is port.

`fgets` reads your file in text form. And you misused `fgets`, when reading same file, there is no need to change the third parameter of `fgets`, you can loop call it until it return NULL.Each time you called `fgets`, using `strtok` to cut the reading line(detail using of `strtok` please google `strtok`).

Comment: Should I read my entire text file in a string and then use strtok to separate ip and port?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code to get line from files. and now you can parse it ahead as your requirements.

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* exit, malloc, realloc, free */
#include <stdio.h>  /* fopen, fgetc, fputs, fwrite */

struct line_reader {
    /* All members are private. */
    FILE    *f;
    char    *buf;
    size_t   siz;
};

/*
 * Initializes a line reader _lr_ for the stream _f_.
 */
void
lr_init(struct line_reader *lr, FILE *f)
{
    lr->f = f;
    lr->buf = NULL;
    lr->siz = 0;
}

/*
 * Reads the next line. If successful, returns a pointer to the line,
 * and sets *len to the number of characters, at least 1. The result is
 * _not_ a C string; it has no terminating '\0'. The returned pointer
 * remains valid until the next call to next_line() or lr_free() with
 * the same _lr_.
 *
 * next_line() returns NULL at end of file, or if there is an error (on
 * the stream, or with memory allocation).
 */
char *
next_line(struct line_reader *lr, size_t *len)
{
    size_t newsiz;
    int c;
    char *newbuf;

    *len = 0;           /* Start with empty line. */
    for (;;) {
        c = fgetc(lr->f);   /* Read next character. */
        if (ferror(lr->f))
            return NULL;

        if (c == EOF) {
            /*
             * End of file is also end of last line,
        `    * unless this last line would be empty.
             */
            if (*len == 0)
                return NULL;
            else
                return lr->buf;
        } else {
            /* Append c to the buffer. */
            if (*len == lr->siz) {
                /* Need a bigger buffer! */
                newsiz = lr->siz + 4096;
                newbuf = realloc(lr->buf, newsiz);
                if (newbuf == NULL)
                    return NULL;
                lr->buf = newbuf;
                lr->siz = newsiz;
            }
            lr->buf[(*len)++] = c;

            /* '\n' is end of line. */
            if (c == '\n')
                return lr->buf;
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Frees internal memory used by _lr_.
 */
void
lr_free(struct line_reader *lr)
{
    free(lr->buf);
    lr->buf = NULL;
    lr->siz = 0;
}

/*
 * Read a file line by line.
 * http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Read_a_file_line_by_line
 */
int
main()
{
    struct line_reader lr;
    FILE *f;
    size_t len;
    char *line;

    f = fopen("foobar.txt", "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        perror("foobar.txt");
        exit(1);
    }

    /*
     * This loop reads each line.
     * Remember that line is not a C string.
     * There is no terminating '\0'.
     */
    lr_init(&lr, f);
    while (line = next_line(&lr, &len)) {
        /*
         * Do something with line.
         */
        fputs("LINE: ", stdout);
        fwrite(line, len, 1, stdout);
    }
    if (!feof(f)) {
        perror("next_line");
        exit(1);
    }
    lr_free(&lr);

    return 0;
}
```

you can get more stuff at http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Read_a_file_line_by_line

Answer (score 1):

The below while loop will do the read part

```
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp))
```

One serious error i saw in ur code is

```
fp = fp++;
```